# SQL XML simple table-column-row entry change edit modify

Tags: sql, xml

How to correct XML entries in a SQL database table-column-row?

**The problem**: I have a SQL database called `MyClients`. The database has three tables:

- dbo.Accounts
- dbo.Organizations
- dbo.Managers

Within the `Accounts` table there are the following columns:

- `AccountID` (PK, varchar(10), not null)
- `OrganizationID` (varchar(10), not null)
- `OrderBy` (int, null)
- `Name` (varchar(250), null)
- `XML` (varchar(max), null)

Some rows are like the following example (I can't seem to get the Markdown HTML editor to properly create a 5-column 2-row table for this, so please forgive the next two lines);

```
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>AccountID</th>
        <th>OrganizationID</th>
        <th>OrderBy</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>XML</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6DC5DB4A</td>
        <td>ECFC36B05A</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Some Company Ltd</td>
<td>&lt;Account&gt;&nbsp;&lt;AccountID&gt;6DC5DB4A&lt;/AccountID&gt;&nbsp;&lt;OrganizationID&gt;ABC567PQR&lt;/OrganizationID&gt;&nbsp;&lt;CreatedDate&gt;1899-12-30 00:00:00&lt;/CreatedDate&gt;&nbsp;&#60/Account&gt;
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

There is a clear problem in rows like this; in the XML column the `<OrganizationID>` entry is not the same as the value in the `OrganizationID` column, **and** the `<CreatedDate>` entry is clearly wrong!

**The question**:

In a large table of about 10,000 rows I have about 30 rows that have been corrupted in this fashion. It's always the same when the corruption exists the `<OrganizationID>` entry is `ABC567PQR` and the `<CreatedDate>` entry is `1899-12-30 00:00:00`.

How do I:

- change the `<CreatedDate>` entry to the correct value of `2012-06-30 13:00:00`
- change the `<OrganizationID>` entry to be the same as is in the `OrganizationID` column for that row?

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....